# how to view a list of spam numbers in galaxy s3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

Ok, I knew how to make a number become spam number in Samsung galaxy s3. That is simple, just tap on that number and click "**Add to spam numbers**". But,

**how to view a list of spam numbers in galaxy s3?**

At this moment, the only way i can do is to check each number one by one by tap on that number and if it appears "**Remove from spam numbers**" then we know that number is spam.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want : (**On Kitkat - 4.4.2**)

> "Settings" > "My Device" > "Call" > "Call Rejection" > "Auto Reject
>   list"

or you can Create an List for Block Numbers.

also,

[Samsung - Remove a number from the reject list](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/27224-samsung-remove-a-number-from-the-reject-list)